# mnesia: intensive usage table

Tags: erlang, mnesia

When I receive such message, like this:

```
** WARNING ** Mnesia is overloaded: {dump_log, write_threshold}
```

what is approach to known **which table** is being used intensively? What kind of debugging do I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say what you should do. Do you have many writes to the same row? which processes use mnesia and how much? Why do you hit the dump-log threshold?

Comment: Added to my todo list to learn the cyrillic alphabet.

Comment: How can I know what request (operation with mnesia) has locked table if it happend?

Comment: The `{dump_log, write_threshold}` happens when the `dump_log` gets written too often. Perhaps you can turn the knob `dump_log_write_threshold` up. It defaults to 100.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting post over on StreamHacker on the subject:

http://streamhacker.com/2008/12/10/how-to-eliminate-mnesia-overload-events/

One of the suggestions in the article is switching to synchronous writes, not sure that this is such a good generic answer.  It would certainly change your scaling characteristics, so don't skip engineering and measuring the change.

However both `dc_dump_limit` and `dump_log_write_threshold` are good settings to play with.  The defaults are somewhat overly sensitive.